# Are Awakened Zoan users able to change form?

Tags: one-piece

We have been introduced to 5 characters (all Impel Down Jailers) with "Awakened" Zoan Devil Fruits. Minotaurus is the most famous of them. A normal Zoan fruit allows the user to transform between Natural (normally human), Animal (based on the devil fruit type), and Hybrid forms.  I can't, however, remember any of the "Mino" guards in any form besides a exageratedly strong version of the Hybrid one.

At the time I thought "Awakened" meant that the fruit was always active so they were stuck as partially animals (as well as give the strengths Crocodile mentioned).  With Doflamingo's Paramecia fruit, however, awakening appears to just unlock new abilities.  This made me doubt my previous understanding.  Wiki doesn't help and I don't have time to rewatch everything.

Do we know whether Awakened Zoan Devil Fruit users retain the ability to transform into multiple forms?

If the answer to this is "Oda hasn't told us yet", that is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe Oda has told us yet, and with how nebulous the definition of what makes for an "awakened" devil fruit user is, without canon stating one way or another there's not really any way we can solidly theorize a yes or no. I would presume that they would retain their ability to transform back and forth because that would make Chopper kind of lame if it didn't (but he'd be a pretty good golfer, because he'd lose all of his points [insert rimshot]), but again, without canon describing it we can't say definitively one way or another.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the "Awakened" Zoan users in Impel Down and Choppers "Monster Point" are the same thing. The first 2 times Chopper used his Monster point (on Drum Island and on Enies Lobby) he had no control over himself, he could not talk or think rationally. He acted on instinct.

Now the Awakened Zoan on ID appeared to have at least rudimentary intelligence and unlike Chopper, did not have undue strain on their bodies.

I think that these differences are from how Chopper achieved his "Awakening". the ID Zoan did it naturally, whereas Chopper does it with his Rumble Ball (By distorting the Devil Fruit wavelength). I think Chopper cheated his way into an awakening when he wasn't physically ready for it and the strain drove him temporarily insane. later when he had boosted himself so that he could use his full 7 points without the rumble ball, his body could now take the strain, but he has still not naturally "Awoken".

I think that if he awakens his devil fruit without using his rumble ball, he will have a more compact version (compared to his current version) of his Monster Point that will be more powerful (because it will not have a distorted wavelength messing with it) and his experience with his incomplete version will let him retain all of his mental abilities